# How to create a Excel like spread sheet in WPF - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I want to create a table like an `Excel` sheet. The table has rows' headers and columns' headers. How to make the rows header move when the vertical scrollbar is dragged and statistic when the horizontal scrollbar is dragged and vice versa for the Columns header like in Excel sheet. Does anyone have any ideas how to do it? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `DataGrid`, try one of these:

[Microsoft datagrid](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) (will be released as part of dot net 4.0, currently in beta)

[Xceed datagrid](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html)

[infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamdatagrid.aspx#Overview)

there's probably a few others too. im pretty sure they all deal with column reordering.